# Prevent an antd form from switching to vertical layout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I want to prevent an antd form from automatically switching to the vertical layout when the window width is shrunk down.
I tried forcing layout={'horizontal'} in the form, but it still switches.

Here's the behavior I'm referring to:
https://d.pr/v/J6qddP

Here's a link to the codepen example:
https://codepen.io/opike99/pen/xxawJge

This is with antd 5.2.0 and react 18.

Codepen code:

```
const { Form, Input, Select, Button, Checkbox } = antd;
const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;

class AntdClassForm extends React.Component {
  formRef = null;
  
  render() {
    console.log('here');
    return (
  <Form
    name="basic"
    // labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
    // wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
    style={{ maxWidth: 300 }}
    layout={'horizontal'}
    initialValues={{ remember: true }}
    // onFinish={onFinish}
    // onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    autoComplete="off"
  >
    <Form.Item
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]}
    >
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>

    <Form.Item
      label="Password"
      name="password"
      rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }]}
    >
      <Input.Password />
    </Form.Item>

    <Form.Item name="remember" valuePropName="checked" wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
      <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
    </Form.Item>

    <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>);
    
  }
 
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(mountNode).render(<AntdClassForm />);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify breakpoints in config provider. Default value to swicth into vertical layout is 575px;

```
 import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
 import { AliasToken } from "antd/lib/theme/interface";

 const customToken: Partial<AliasToken> = {
     <!-- Specify breakpoints when switch of layouts happens -->
    "screenXSMax": 360,
    "screenXS": 300,
    "screenXSMin": 280
 }

<ConfigProvider theme={{ token: customToken}}>
     <!-- Your antd code -->
</ConfigProvider>
```